# In Rails (7.0.4) , Is there any way to change a attribute name from all over our application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I wanna change "Author" to "Author_name" in my rails application.

So I have used "rename_column" method in the migration, then after running migration my column name is changed but after that I have to manually change it everywhere from my code ( Controller and view )

Comment: Yes no other choice than changing everywhere. Maybe your editor / IDE can identify all occurences of `author` in your application.Also if you work on linux, you can use the grep function: `grep -rl 'editor'`. It will show all files containing the word `author`

Comment: You can likely just do a directory wide search for something like `.author` and then change them all over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have got my solution, This is a editor problem not a Rails one.
I'm using Vs-code, we can do `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`H`.
It will open a search and replace window.

[image]

You can change whatever you wanna change,

[image]

Thank you.